# Fire PushNotifications at Specific times - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications, uipickerview

Hi I was wondering if there was a way to display a push notification with the user's approval on specific days. I currently have a toggle for Push Notifications, and when this toggle is called, it should display a picker view for when the user would like these notifications to come. For example, the user could choose the notifications to come weekly, daily, monthly(this would be really nice), or yearly. Also, having the user able to choose which days it comes specifically would be a nice touch. I am not sure as to how I could do this. I would appreciate any guidance or help throughout this process.

***Background:*** I am making an app for my high school's newspaper and would like to remind the user to check out the app. Notifying the user on the first of every month would be nice because our school releases a new issue out on the first of every month.

Here are is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcKSz.png) of what my app looks like now.

Here is my current AppDelegate.swift code as well for reference:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.swift
//  TheGunnOracleApp
//
//  Created by Rajat Khare on 11/22/16.
//  Copyright © 2016 RDKhare. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {




        if(!UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce"))
        {

            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "HasLaunchedOnce")
            UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        }
        else{

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

            self.window!.rootViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartAfterFirst")

            self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        }



        if Reachability.checkIntenetRechable() == false {



            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "The Internet connection appears to be offline. Please connect to Wi-Fi or use Cellular Data to continue", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)

            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))

            self.window?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }


        return true
    }





    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {





        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, performActionFor shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {

        if shortcutItem.type == "com.rdkhare.Home"{

            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let frontNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VCHome")
            let rearNavigationController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menuVC")
            let mainRevealController : SWRevealViewController = SWRevealViewController(rearViewController: rearNavigationController, frontViewController: frontNavigationController)

            self.window?.rootViewController? = mainRevealController
//            let homeVC = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homePage1") as! WebViewHome
//            let root = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
//            let navController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: homeVC)
//            root?.present(navController, animated: true, completion: {
//                completionHandler(true)


//            })

    }




    }


}
```